# Resnet for Text data

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, resnet

Hi I want to use ResNet for Text data. I tried to look some code example lot of other data at the end I wrote the following code. But I'm not sure it's the correct way for ResNet or not.

NOTE::: this part is optional if i recieve an opinion on it. it will be great but I'm going to try it once the above one is corrected. if it is correct way then I want it to implement it in this way ----> ResNet should contain 18 layers in total whereas these layers should be divided into four stages and each stage should consist of two convolutional blocks. Each convolutional block should contain two convolutional layers with batch normalization and ReLU non_linearity in-between. Then, ResNet should pass the output from the convolutional layers to two fully-connected layers that will use the reduced data to classify the initial data to a given website class. Last but not least, you should use Adam optimizer and categorical cross-entropy (typically used for multi-class classification problems). Make sure that you identify and use the optimal hyper-parameters for your ResNet.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics
from scipy.stats import zscore
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation



class ResNet_class():

    def __init__(self):
        # Cross-Validate
        self.no_of_folds = int(input('enter no of K_fold: '))
        self.kf = KFold(self.no_of_folds, shuffle=True, random_state=42)  # Use for KFold classification
        self.EPOCHS = int(input('enter no of epochs: '))

    def check_test(self):
        df = pd.read_csv(
            "https://data.heatonresearch.com/data/t81-558/jh-simple-dataset.csv",
            na_values=['NA','?'])
        df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['job'],prefix="job")],axis=1)
        df.drop('job', axis=1, inplace=True)
        df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['area'],prefix="area")],axis=1)
        df.drop('area', axis=1, inplace=True)
        df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['product'],prefix="product")],axis=1)
        df.drop('product', axis=1, inplace=True)
        med = df['income'].median()
        df['income'] = df['income'].fillna(med)
        df['income'] = zscore(df['income'])
        df['aspect'] = zscore(df['aspect'])
        df['save_rate'] = zscore(df['save_rate'])
        df['subscriptions'] = zscore(df['subscriptions'])
        x_columns = df.columns.drop('age').drop('id')
        x = df[x_columns].values
        y = df['age'].values
        oos_y = []
        oos_pred = [] 
        fold = 0
        for train, test in self.kf.split(x):
            fold += 1
            print(f"Fold #{fold}")   
            x_train = x[train]
            y_train = y[train]
            x_test = x[test]
            y_test = y[test]
            model = Sequential()
            model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=x.shape[1], activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
            model.add(Dense(1))
            model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
            model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=0,
                      epochs=self.EPOCHS)
            pred = model.predict(x_test)
            oos_y.append(y_test)
            oos_pred.append(pred)
            score = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(pred, y_test))
            print(f"Fold score (RMSE): {score}")
        oos_y = np.concatenate(oos_y)
        oos_pred = np.concatenate(oos_pred)
        score = np.sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(oos_pred, oos_y))
        print(f"Final, out of sample score (RMSE): {score}")
        oos_y = pd.DataFrame(oos_y)
        oos_pred = pd.DataFrame(oos_pred)
        oosDF = pd.concat([df, oos_y, oos_pred], axis=1)
resnet = ResNet_class()
resnet.check_test()
```

Comment: To start, you need to implement ResNet using the Functional API, not the Sequential API.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I tried to do it but can't successed. I'll be glad if you show me with this csv how to do it.